# Why does Zankyou no Terror's OP end with a disclaimer?

Tags: anime-production, zankyou-no-terror

At the end of Zankyou no Terror's OP, a disclaimer is displayed. It reads:

> This show is a work of fiction. Any resemblance to real people or groups is coincidental."

[image: Disclaimer at the end of the OP]

The disclaimer is there because the series depicts terrorist acts and whatnot, but:

Is this disclaimer something **the team decided** to put in order to safeguard themselves?
Or are there specific regulations that **make them** put it there, given the nature of the show?

Also, I'd never seen this type of disclaimer in an anime series before. Are there any other series that also have them?

Comment: If it appears in virtually all Anime, and sometimes along with a notice about watching in a well lit room. It usually appears after OP but doesn't always get subbed.

Comment: I noticed it (in english) in the closing of episodes of http://www.crunchyroll.com/soranowoto

Answer (score 5):

It's only a speculation, but my best guess is that Zankyou no Terror is handling with a real life scenario that just **might happen** to us in the real world (and that's little scary).

Unlike other animes that have super powers (like a Death Note, or an ability to launch a destructive energy projectile, etc.), in this anime, there are no supernatural abilities as far as it's shown to us.

So the author of the series wants to give us some sort of "warning" that what we see is not really based on events in real life, and the we shouldn't start copying the protagonist behavior (And if we do, the owners are not legally responsible for it).

Comment: Congrats on your 2k :)